# Missing 64-bit support for iOS application

Tags: ios, xcode, arm64, base-sdk, iphone-64bit

I'm getting warning for 64-bit support missing. The whole message is like below:

Missing 64-bit support - Beginning on February 1, 2015 new iOS apps submitted to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK. Beginning June 1, 2015 app updates will also need to follow the same requirements. To enable 64-bit in your project, we recommend using the default Xcode build setting of “Standard architectures” to build a single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit code.

I've done changes like attached image for **Valid Architectures**.
[image]

If i try to Archive the build with supporting **arm64**. I'm getting following errors.
[image]

If i will remove **arm64** from Valid Architectures, it will work fine and submitted successfully to iTunes Connect but i get mail from iTunes that binary is missing 64-bit support.

I have done googling but not able to get exact solution. Please help me for getting out of this issue.
Any help will be surely worth appreciate.

Thanks,

Comment: From the error logs, it looks like you are using third party static libraries (from amazon?) whose binaries do not support arm64 yet. Check with the vendor if they have released an updated version (one that supports arm64), and if not, when they will release it. Every third part developer should have been scrambling for a while in preparation for this deadline (at least, Unity3d was). I don't think there is anything you can do on your own to solve this.

Comment: Which version of AWS SDK you are using? Try with 1.7.0 or higher, check this : https://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/iOS/7003308162044672

Answer (score 3):

Amazon iOS SDK offers 64bit support since the version 1.7.0

https://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/iOS/7003308162044672

Simply use their latest version 2.1.0  , and it will compile with arm64 flag.

Comment: This seems like perfect solution. I need to go through it. Once this will solve my issue, i'll surely accept this answer. Till UpVote you surely deserve.

Answer (score 0):

That means your library is not compiled for 64 bit, arm64 and your app is expecting it,

There should be new version of that library which supports arm64, just check the developer's web site.

http://aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdk/

Answer (score 0):

Simply update valid architectures and add arm64 flag in Xcode it's not the only step that you need to make an application 64-bit compatible.

Your log is telling you that **one library at least it has not been compiled for 64-bit**. So update your libraries, in particular from the logs I think you need update the **Amazon library**.